# Translate animation is behind other layout

Tags: android, layout

I have four linear layouts in my screen.

The first layout contain a textview.

I'm trying to move my textView to the the fourth layout of the right with a translate animation.

But when i do that the text view move behind the other layout and if i move my layout from the fourth layout of the right to the first at the left it's ok.

Im my xml  i have put : in all layouts

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

[image](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=282578screen.png)

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to call a bringToFront on the layout?

Comment: yes but that doesn't work

Comment: check my answer, it works and tested

Answer (score 0):

Use setZAdjustment to put your View in front of the other Views.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setZAdjustment%28int%29

Comment: Are you sure you are using one of `ZORDER_NORMAL`, `ZORDER_TOP`, or `ZORDER_BOTTOM`?

Answer (score 0):

Pre-Kitkat :

```
yourLayout.bringToFront();
((View)yourLayout.getParent()).requestLayout();
((View)yourLayout.getParent()).invalidate();
```

KitKat :

```
yourLayout.bringToFront();
```

Comment: if i do that the animation doesn't start to the good coordianate

Comment: Could you please elborate *"start to the good coordianate"* ?

Answer (score 0):

Android linear layout construction starts from first element from the beginning. So any element defined first will be created and then rest, so no matter what you do, you cannot achieve with linear layout. Try with relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/testAnimTranslate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="#0000dd"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#0dd0dd"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#ddd0dd"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#44d0dd"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
     </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAnimate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/testAnimTranslate"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/testAnimTranslate"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/testAnimTranslate"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="qweqwew" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Define your translate anim in anim folder or programatically. make sure to add

```
    LinearInterpolator
    setFillAfter to true
```

and start the anim

Answer (score 0):

I think you create the view in the code, so you should add setClipChildren(false)
in your constructor too.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#ZORDER_TOP):

> ZORDER_TOP: Requests that the content being animated be forced on top of all other content for **the duration of the animation**.

Please check that `setFillAfter(true)` does not match this usage. 
Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with what you are trying to do, is that you want to draw a View outside of its parent. It goes behind the other LinearLayouts because they are drawn after the LinearLayout parent of the View. Even if it is brought to the front, it seems that only relates to children within a single parent?

If you look at how Fragment animations work, you need to recreate the Fragment to translate a from one Frame into another. You also need two separate animations.

BlackBeard's solution will work because it makes the TextView a child of the outermost parent and declares it last. This means the TextView is drawn after everything else and therefore will be drawn on top of everything else.

This doesn't achieve what I think you are trying to do. If you want the TextView to belong to its destination LinearLayout after the animation you'll need to recreate the TextView and add it to the LinearLayout in the correct position in the hierarchy. You'll also need a second animation to move the new TextView into its position.

If done properly the animations should overlay each other perfectly and if in a LinearLayout one or the other of the animated Views will pass on top of everything else.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFAABBCC"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="I'm some text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFBBCCAA"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFCCAABB"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFBBAACC"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
private LinearLayout mLayout1;
private LinearLayout mLayout2;
private LinearLayout mLayout3;
private LinearLayout mLayout4;
private TextView mTextView;
private View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    mLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    mLayout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
    mLayout4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout4);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // simple trigger to start the animation.
            startAnimation();
            mTextView.setOnTouchListener(null);
            return true;
        }
    };
    mTextView.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
}

private void startAnimation() {

    final LinearLayout origin = (LinearLayout) mTextView.getParent();
    LinearLayout destination = null;
    // I'm not sure what kind of behaviour you want. This just randomises the destination.
    do {
        switch (new Random().nextInt(4)) {
            case 0:
                destination = mLayout1;
                break;
            case 1:
                destination = mLayout2;
                break;
            case 2:
                destination = mLayout3;
                break;
            case 3:
                destination = mLayout4;
                break;
            default:
        }
        // if destination == origin or is null, try again.
    } while (destination == origin || destination == null);

    // Create another TextView and initialise it to match mTextView
    final TextView textViewNew = new TextView(this);
    textViewNew.setText(mTextView.getText());
    textViewNew.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mTextView.getTextSize());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textViewNew.setLayoutParams(params);
    textViewNew.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);

    // Add the new TextView to the destination LinearLayout
    destination.addView(textViewNew);

    // Create animations based on origin and destination LinearLayouts
    ObjectAnimator outAnimator = getOutAnimator(origin, destination);
    // The in animator also requires a reference to the new TextView
    ObjectAnimator inAnimator = getInAnimator(textViewNew, origin, destination);
    // All animators must be created before any are started because they are calculated
    // using values that are modified by the animation itself.
    outAnimator.start();
    inAnimator.start();
    // Add a listener to update mTextView reference to the new TextView when complete.
    inAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

            origin.removeView(mTextView);
            mTextView = textViewNew;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    });
}

/**
 * This method creates an ObjectAnimator to move the existing TextView out of its parent
 * towards its destination
 */
private ObjectAnimator getOutAnimator(View origin, View destination) {

    // Calculate the difference between x of destination and of origin
    float layoutDifferenceX = destination.getX() - origin.getX();
    // initialX is simply mTextView.getX()
    // the distance moved == layoutDifferenceX
    float finalX = mTextView.getX() + layoutDifferenceX;

    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTextView, "x",
            mTextView.getX(), finalX);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(500);

    return animator;
}

/**
 * This method creates an ObjectAnimator to move the new TextView from the initial position
 * of mTextView, relative to the new TextView's parent, to its destination.
 */
private ObjectAnimator getInAnimator(View newView, View origin, View destination) {

    // Calculate the difference between x of destination and of origin
    float layoutDifferenceX = destination.getX() - origin.getX();
    // initialX relative to destination
    float initialX = mTextView.getX() - layoutDifferenceX;

    // finalX relative to destination == initialX relative to origin
    float finalX = mTextView.getX();

    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(newView, "x",
            initialX, finalX);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(500);

    return animator;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

EDIT: You could also declare the TextView in xml and inflate it to get rid of all the code initialising it.